# Scale an image instead of wrapping text around it when the browser window is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, scaling

I have an image positioned next to a div with some text by using display: inline on the div.
When the browser window is resized to be more narrow, I would like the image to scale down instead of having the text wrap around it first.

Currently, the text will wrap under the image when the window is resized, and only then will the image scale thanks to its max-width.

The end goal is to have a horizontal logo next to a horizontal menu, and have the logo scale on window resize while the menu stays in place.

Would be great if this could be done with just CSS, but I'll take Javascript if that's not possible.

```
<style>
img { max-width: 100%; }
#textblock { display: inline}
</style>

<div id="container">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
  <div id="textblock">Some Random Text</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLc8dcsh/1/

Comment: Adding a minimum width to your image might solve your problem.

Comment: How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uLc8dcsh/2/)?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py it's warmer, but I would like the image scaling to start with the text still fully visible.

Comment: @CorrupterofCode if you add a width to <div id="container"> in chipChocolate.py's example then you will be able to keep the text fully visible. jsFiddle allows overflow so if you don't set a pixel width then the image and content has nothing to base its scaling on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="div1"> img tag should be here  </div>
    <div id="textblock">   </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    float:left;

}
.div1{width:80%; float:left;}
#textblock {
    display: inline;
    float:right;
    width:20%;
}
#container{width:100%; float:left; }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I wanted!  However on the real site, percentages for the logo and the text didn't look good at every resolution.  For example, it would look good at 80/20 split at a narrow window size, but better as 60/40 at a wider size.  I ended up using jQuery to dynamically adjust the ratio, but your answer gave me the framework to set it all up!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/uLc8dcsh/3/ ?

1. Here the logo will grow max to width of 300px when you maximize the window.
2. The minimum width of the container is set to 300px so the word will not wrap
3. the logo's width is 50%, means 50% of the `#container` width

```css
img {
    width:50%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
#textblock {
    display: inline
}

#container {
    min-width: 300px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably overkill:

**What is this:**

**1.** Float image, overflow hidden

This if so the text does not overflow under the image

**2.** added clear-fix to containing div

This is so the image does not destroy the outside element (article)

**Html**

```
<article class="clearfix">
    <img src="some image"></img>
    <p>Some random text</p> 
</article>
```

**css**

```
article p {
    overflow:hidden;
}
article img {
    float:left;
    max-width:80%;
}
article {
    border:1px solid;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

**And here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLc8dcsh/4/)**